# Why reference object has 04/10/2016?

Tags: java

I didn't understand why date2 printing `04/10/2016`,

1) i didn't call method which has RETURN
 2) there are two methods, with same Parameter but diff output

```
MyDate date2 = new MyDate(4,10,2008);
        System.out.println(date2);

----------------------------------------
//MyDate class
public class MyDate{

 public int day;
 public int month;
 public int year;


public MyDate(){
}

//Constructor that takes 3 arguments
public MyDate(int m, int d, int y){
setDate(m, d, y);
}
//Methods

public String toString1(){
return day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
}

public String toString(){
return month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
}

public void setDate(int m, int d, int y){
day = d;
year = y;
month = m;
}
}
```

Comment: What output did you expect?

Comment: So you wonder why adding arbitrary numbers to the `toString` method name doesn't count as "working"?

Comment: Tried using code, norepro.

Comment: My confusion is i have just created object reference, but not called any method 
like       String var1 = date2.toString(); 
but date2 has Retrun value from toString()

Comment: So you didn't bother to check what `System.out.println` does? Too much effort?

Answer (score 1):

It internally invokes `toString()` when you try to convert an `Object` to `String` and in your case which is implemented to print it

Comment: So why it's not invoking toString1()?

Comment: because it is coded to invoke [`toString()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.valueOf%28java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: @MAS400 `System.out.println` invokes `toString()` specifically, not `toString1()` or any other method.

Answer (score 0):

> I didn't understand why date2 printing 04/10/2016,

With the `MyDate` class and its `toString()` method, `System.out.println(date2)` should print `4/10/2016` since an `int` is not a String `formater` and so doesn't add a `0` prefix.

```
public class MyDate{

 public int day;
 public int month;
 public int year;

...
   public String toString(){
     return month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
   }
...
}
```

---

**Edit for comment**

As you are beginner, I will try to decompose but stay simple.

Your interrogation comes from what this method does :

```
    System.out.println(date2);
```

First : you have to understand what this line means. 
Here, you call the `println()` method of the `out` `PrintStream` field of the `System` class and you provide as parameter of the method the `date2` variable which is an instance of `MyDate`.
Which should interest you here is what `println()` does.
The naming may make you guess that it has a relation with the display of something and it is the case but nothing is better than the javadoc and the source code of a class to understand it.

`println()` is a overloaded method of `PrintStream`. So you have to identify which one method is called. The single method which takes as parameter a type compatible with `MyDate` is `void java.io.PrintStream.println(Object x)`.
For information, all classes derive from the `Object` class, therefore `MyDate` IS a `Object`.

Look at its javadoc :

**java.io.PrintStream**

**void java.io.PrintStream.println(Object x)**

> Prints an Object and then terminate the line. This method calls at
>   first String.valueOf(x) to get the printed object's string value, then
>   behaves as though it invokes print(String) and then println().
>
> Parameters: x The Object to be printed.

It is rather clear what the method does :

- it calls `String.valueOf(x)` to get the `String` value of the `x` object
- then it print the retrieved String value from `x`.

But what does `String.valueOf(x)` ?

There again, javadoc and code source will help you :

```
/**
 * Returns the string representation of the {@code Object} argument.
 *
 * @param   obj   an {@code Object}.
 * @return  if the argument is {@code null}, then a string equal to
 *          {@code "null"}; otherwise, the value of
 *          {@code obj.toString()} is returned.
 * @see     java.lang.Object#toString()
 */
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
}
```

it returns the  result of the `toString()` method on the `obj` parameter if  `obj` is not null, otherwhise it returns the "null" String.

Come back to your code now.
Inside, you declare these two methods :

```
public String toString1(){
  return day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
}

public String toString(){
  return month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
}
```

`toString()` is therefore logically called and you should remove or rename the `toString1()` method as it is error-prone named.

If you want to format your `MyDate` instance according to several formats, you should have two methods to perform it but you should avoid mixing a custom method with a `toString()` method.

You could have for example :

```
public String toStringInDDMMYYYY(){
 ...
}

public String toStringInMMDDYYYY(){
 ...
}
```

Besides, you could use `SimpleDateFormat` to format your date and use `Date` objects rather than custom `Date` objects but as you start in Java, I may understand what you test different things.

Comment: And that's what it *does* print for me, so well and good.  I'm just not sure whether this answers the question the OP is trying, not very successfully, to ask.

Comment: Probably. It was to express the fact that the question and the described problem don't reflect what the code actually does.

Comment: *****I am new bee in JAVA world, just started learning****  
I am not worried about prefix 0, 
My question is when object reference created, without evoking toString() , why date2 has return value from toString()

If you say system will evoke this method toString(), then why not other similar method toString1(), which has same number of input and diff output?

Comment: I understand. I will try to help you. I updated  my answer. If you have any  question don't hesitate.

Comment: Thanks David for detail response..... i got you point and now have better understanding.....Thanks Again....